# dbt - pass return value of dbt macro to python

Tags: python, dbt

Since version 1.5, dbt can be invoked directly from within a python script, like:

```py
from dbt.cli.main import dbtRunner, dbtRunnerResult

# initialize
dbt = dbtRunner()

# create CLI args as a list of strings
cli_args = ["run-operation", "get_something_macro"]

# run the command
res: dbtRunnerResult = dbt.invoke(cli_args)

# inspect the results
for r in res.result:
    print(f"{r}")
```

See:
https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/programmatic-invocations

Lets say I have a simple macro that returns something for example:

```
{% macro get_current_catalog() %}

    {{ return(target.catalog) }}

{% endmacro %}
```

How do I get the return value into python?

My only idea so far is using `print("...")` or `log("...", info=True)` within the macro and capture stdout. But I thought there has to be a better way...

Maybe some of you guys / gals know.